# how to use a variable more than once in Spring EL?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-el

If I have the following classes

```
public class A {
    String c;
    B b;
    public String getSome(String x) {              
          //some processing setting some
          return some;
    }
    public B getB() { return b; }
    public String getC() { return c; }
    ....
}
class B {
    public String getSome(String key) {
        //some processing setting some
        return some;
    }
    //...
}
```

Suppose my model object is A in some jsp.
How can I show the value of:

```
model.getSome(model.getB().getSome(model.getC()))
```

which is equivalent to:

```
 String c = model.getC();
 B b = model.getB();
 String someFromB = b.getSome(c);
 String someFromA = model.getSome(someFromB);
```

using Scriptlets I would do:

```
<% 
    A model = request.getAttibute("MODEL");
%> 
THE RESULT IS: <%= model.getSome(model.getB().getSome(model.getC())) %>
```

How is that done in Spring EL?

please don't send me references to the Spring EL documentation.
I've read it and still don't know how to do it.
Just please write how you would do it if it's possible.